# Как запомнить адрес на предыдущую структуру мин.элем-та в списке?

Tags: c++

Как можно сохранить адрес структуры, которая находиться перед минимальным элементом?
Список односвязный!
Вот функция:

```
Single_List Find_Min_Elem(Single_List* Head) {
//элементы списка(к примеру): 7 5 9 3 1 5
Single_List *temp = Head;
Single_List *temp2 = temp->Next;
Single_List *preMin= temp;//адрес предыдущего элемента миним 
//структуры(нужен для того, чтобы не потерять)

for (int i = 0;i < 5; i++) {
if ((temp->Data) < (temp2->Data)) {

    temp2 = (temp2->Next);
}//end if
else {
    temp = temp2;
    temp2 = (temp2->Next);

}//else
}//for
return *preMin;
}
```

Где нужно использовать preMin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Single_List* Find_Min_Elem(Single_List* Head)
{
    Single_List* preMin(nullptr);
    for(Single_List* cur(Head); cur && cur->Next; cur = cur->Next)
        if((preMin && preMin->Next->Data > cur->Next->Data) || (!preMin && Head->Data > cur->Next->Data))
            preMin = cur;
    return preMin;
}
```

В моем коде, если минимальным элементом списка является первый элемент, то preMin будет иметь значение nullptr, что означает, что у минимального элемента списка нет предыдущего элемента. В своем коде вы инициализируете preMin указателем на голову списка, что наталкивает на мысль, что в вышеописанном случае он nullptr'у никогда не должен быть равен ... В общем, не понимая, каким должен быть результат функции, в случае минимального первого элемента, я оставил для данного случая preMin равным nullptr.

Comment: Используйте `nullptr` вместо `NULL`, давно пора переходить на «нормалный C++»

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, подправил сообщение.

Comment: `std::` перед `nullptr` не надо